# Connect to HCatalog using Spark / Spark SQL / Java

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql, hcatalog

How to connect to HCatalog to get the data's stored in Hive [Hive metastore] using Spark / Spark SQL / Java

Do we need to use HiveContext() for this? how do i configure Hcatalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your existing hive-site.xml into Spark's configuration and then create a HiveContext. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables .

Comment: Thanks @Holden , is spark using HCatalog to connect to hive meta-store or some other way?